# exercise on poisson distribution.

Tags: probability

Assume number of messages input to  a communication channel in an interval of duration **t** seconds is poisson distributed by parameter **0.3t**.Find the probability that:

At most 20 messages arrive in an interval of 20 seconds.

**My try**

Since at most 20 messages are allowed,I did this.

```
P(X=1) + P(X=2) + ......P(X=20).
```

which According to me is:

```
e^(-.3(20)) * (.3(20)^20)/20! + ........
```

Am i correct in saying that P(X=1) is

```
e^(-.3(20)) * (.3(20)^20)/20!
```

and is my method correct or is there a shorter method?

Comment: Since you only expect $6$ messages in $20$ seconds, the probability of at most $20$ messages is going to be very close to $1$

Comment: @Henry ok ,but what is the right and smarter way to compute it?

Comment: I would use the R code `ppois(20,6)` which is slightly less than $1-P(X=21)-P(X=22)$

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing $P(X=0)$

$P(X=1)=\dfrac{e^{-0.3 \times 20} (0.3 \times 20)^1}{1!}$ and more generally $P(X=n)=\dfrac{e^{-0.3 \times 20} (0.3 \times 20)^n}{n!}$